# Add scrollbar to JFACE Wizard

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, jface

### Problem

I have a Composite in my wizardPage and I want to add scrollbars to it if the Composite is bigger than the wizard window, but no method I tried so far worked. Anyone an idea how to add the scrollbars?

I want to add them to a Composite to which I add text;

```
compositeInfo = new Composite(container, SWT.BORDER);
```

### What I tried

I tried creating a ScrollableComposite without succes, when I use the ScrollableComponent, the text doesnt get added to the Composite.

```
compositeInfo = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
compositeInfo.setBackground(SWTResourceManager
            .getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1, false);
gl.numColumns = 1;
compositeInfo.setLayout(gl);
GridData gd_composite_2 = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false,
        false, 2, 1);
gd_composite_2.widthHint = 450;
compositeInfo.setLayoutData(gd_composite_2);
```

add some text

```
c = compositeInfo;
Label lblGD = new Label(c, SWT.NONE);
GridData gd_lblG = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1,
                    1);
gd_lblG.widthHint = 450;
    lblGD.setLayoutData(gd_lblG);
    lblGD.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
    lblGD.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 10, SWT.BOLD));
    lblGD.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblGD.setAlignment(SWT.LEFT);
    lblGD.setText(t);
    ((ScrolledComposite) c).setContent(lblGD);
```

Comment: I was able to display the information in the ScrollableComponent by adding a component so you have to 
1. Create a ScrolledComposite
2. Add a Composite to ScrolledComposite
3. Add your text to the Composite

But when I now do an action on the WizardPage which updates the Composite I get the message "Composite Disposed" -- so ScrolledComposite automaticly disposes the Composite.. anyone an idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

See JavaDoc of [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html). You need to call either `compositeInfo.setSize` or `compositeInfo.setMinSize`.

Comment: I tried it, but without succes; `compositeInfo.setSize(400, 100);` the composite is still empty.

I also checked the JavaDoc I couldnt figure out what I'm doing wrong